# Dockerfile write multiple string with variable to file - string not interpolated

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Trying the following script in Dockerfile to write multiple lines with variable to file:

```
ARG LIBSPARKODBC_PATH
RUN LIBSPARKODBC_PATH=$(find / -name libsparkodbc_sb64.so) && echo '[Simba Spark]'
Driver=$LIBSPARKODBC_PATH' >> /etc/odbc.ini
```

But this results to the following content in /etc/odbc.ini file:

[Simba Spark]

Driver=$LIBSPARKODBC_PATH

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you try using double quotes?

Comment: @Jib is spot-on. In bash, single quotes print the string verbatim. For variable substitution, we need to use no quotes or double quotes. Just try running `FOO="bar"; echo 'single qoutes FOO=$FOO'; echo "doulbe quotes FOO=$FOO"; echo no quotes FOO=$FOO;`

Comment: I managed to get it working with this: RUN LIBSPARKODBC_PATH=$(find / -name libsparkodbc_sb64.so) && echo '[Simba Spark]' >> /etc/odbc.ini && echo "Driver=$LIBSPARKODBC_PATH" >> /etc/odbc.ini

Comment: But not sure how this could be done with single echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to insert the content of a variable in the output of an `echo` command you have to use double quotes `"` instead of single quote `'`.

For printing multiple lines with a single `echo` command you can insert line feed character `\n`.

Your sample code would then looks like:

```bash
ARG LIBSPARKODBC_PATH
RUN LIBSPARKODBC_PATH=$(find / -name libsparkodbc_sb64.so) && \
    echo "[Simba Spark]\nDriver=$LIBSPARKODBC_PATH" >> /etc/odbc.ini
```

Which, in the target file, will render as:

```
[Simba Spark]
Driver=...
```

**NOTE** that the `>>` will append to the file. Thus, running multiple time your script will most-likely result in having multiple times that same line in the file ..